# Accepted bounty Question vanished with both question and answers?

Tags: support

After a while(rawly 2 months) a accepted answer and Question with a bounty reward to me vanished. I cannot see my comments nor the answer I posted in my Profile/answers tab either.

I am just wondering if this is a feature of some sort or a bug? I also tried searching for that particular question and its context but could not find anything either so I cannot provide a link to that SO question.

The question rewarding the bounty was about the pinterest api and possibility to count users.

Comment: Link to question (OP, +10k users and moderators only): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226315/pinterest-followers-display/17346789

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post was auto culled after the user that posted the question requested that their account be removed, since the question had a negative score.

Since the answer was good, and a bounty took place, and the question wasn't so horrible that I couldn't fix it up a bit ... I:

- Fixed up the question a bit, it's not stellar, but it's better
- Fixed up the answer a bit
- Restored the question

Once in a while a few gems in the rough go out in the night in a similar twist of fate, if you notice a *really* good answer to something that was deleted but looks fixable, fix it if you can and / or flag it for restoration indicating that you (have/will)(fixed/fix) the question since the answer was just fantastic.

Comment: thanks for clearing this situation so fast and well.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the questions was deleted by a moderator or three 10k users. When a question is deleted, it pretty much vanishes from the sight of all non-10k users.

Also, you probably lost the rep you gained from upvotes on the answer.

Edit: Oded has confirmed that the user was destroyed by a moderator, causing the system to automagically delete all their negatively voted posts.

Comment: The *user* was deleted. `Community` then took care of the post, as it had a negative score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - you are right.

Comment: @Martijn Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

[Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17226315/447356). Screenshot for <10K users:

> [image]

The user account was "nuked" by a moderator for some reason, and part of such a process is auto deletion of all posts from that user with negative score.

That said, looks like that specific question might be worth keeping so I already flagged for moderator attention, will update when there will be any changes.